# Assert big JSON responses in DRF uni testing

Tags: json, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

What is the best strategy when trying to validate big JSON responses inside DRF unit tests?

For example:

```
class MyUnitTest(APITestCase):
    def some_unit_test(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('url'), data, format='json')
```

This method can return a big response with varying data inside it which I would like to verify. Should I just 'hardcode' the expected response for each method call? Or there is a more 'smart' way of generating the expected response and doing this assertion?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you exactly want to test... Using `client.get()` is more like an integration test as the whole stack from views, to models, serialization etc. will be involved... Maybe you just want to test serialization, fetching data etc...?

Comment: @BernhardVallant I guess it is more oriented to integration testing and treating the system as a black box.